# Why span can't be displayed at the same line with div?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}    

div.header{
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

div.header_inside{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>header</span>
  <div class="header_inside">header_inside</div>            
</div>
```

The text `header` is in the span label,it is a inline element,why it can't be displayed at the same line (or say,at the same height) with div `header_inside`?
To add `margin-top:-20px;` in css of div.header_inside can make text in span displayed at the same line with  div `header_inside`,it is not my problem.

Comment: There's no `<span>` in your code, or I just understood question incorectly

Comment: @AleshaOleg `<span>header</span>`...

Comment: @AleshaOleg — It's on line 1 of the HTML.

Comment: hmm, missed it. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A div is, by default, `display: block` so it generates a block box with line breaks before and after it.

If you want it on the same line as some inline content, you'll need to change it to `display: inline`, `display: inline-block`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A `div` is a block element and need all the space. So no other element can be placed beside a block element. So you have to change the `display` of the `div` to `inline` or `inline-block`. You can change your code to the following:

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}    
div.header {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
div.header_inside{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>header</span>
  <div class="header_inside">header_inside</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "inline-block" property, so still a inline element but u can add width and height

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}    
div.header{
width:300px;
height:150px;
border:1px solid red;
}
div.header_inside{
margin:0 auto;
width:150px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="header"><span>header</span>
        <div class="header_inside">header_inside               
        </div>            
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```